# bucles y condicionales en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un  una duda sobre python y es que recien estoy aprendiendo y en teoria me ejecuta bien pero....

```
contador=0
early='\nescribe\n'
inicio=print('hola escribe tu nombre\n')
nombre=input()
mid=print('hola',nombre,'dime tu edad para ayudarte con la votación\n')
edad=int(input())   
valor=True
while valor:
    contador=contador+1
    if contador>1:
        valor=False
    if edad<18:
        print('no puedes votar')
        msg=input(early)
    else:
        print('puedes votar')
        valor=False
```

como ven en la imagen no recorre el for ni el if, se queda estancado y asi cumpla la condicion no sale 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: ¿cual bucle `for`, te refieres al bucle `while`?

Comment: En el `if edad<18` vuelves a leer el input del usuario ¿esperas que ese input se procese como una nueva edad y que si es mayor de 18 salga del bucle? En ese caso el problema está que la edad leida con este `input()` interno la guardas en `msg`, y deberías seguidamente hacer `edad=int(msg)` para que se tenga en cuenta como edad en la siguiente iteración del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que lo que quieres hacer es que te pregunte la edad siempre hasta que pongas una mayor de 18... El codigo deberia de funcionar asi:

```
nombre = input('hola escribe tu nombre\n')
texto = "hola " + nombre + " dime tu edad para ayudarte con la votación\n"
edad = int(input(texto))
def mayorDeEdad(nombre):
    #Definir una función que se ejecute infinitamente mientras "edad" sea menor que 18
    global edad
    if edad < 18:
        print("No puedes votar")
        edad = int(input("¿Cuantos años tienes?"))
        mayorDeEdad(nombre)
    else:
        print('puedes votar')
        return
mayorDeEdad(nombre)
```

Si no funciona en tu ordenador intenta eliminar los espacios y volverlos a poner (me refiero a las tabulaciones, las sangrías, los espacios del principio de la linea)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que, cuando te diga si puede votar o no, te vuelva a preguntar la edad, quita lo de if contador > 1: valor = false. Quitando eso, te hace el bucle for sin parar hasta que tú lo pares.

Comment: De hecho, no hay ningún bucle for...

Comment: Perdón, bucle while.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que no estas sobre escribiendo el valor de `edad` y se queda con el valor inicial, deberias de tener algo como esto:

```
while valor:
    if edad<18:
        print('no puedes votar')
        edad=int(input(early))
    else:
        print('puedes votar')
        valor=False
```

con este cambio `edad=int(input(early))` el valor se actualizará y en el siguiente bucle entrará a la condición que le corresponde.